# SQL порядок операторов в запросе

Tags: sql

В каких вариантах верно указан порядок операторов в запросе? Верно только 1 и 4? Или есть тонкости?

1. Select... from... group by
2. select... where... from... order by
3. Select... from... order by... having
4. Select distinct... from... where

Comment: Если нет "запиканых" скобок - да.

Answer (score 1):

Классическая схема для одной таблицы

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] column_list
FROM table_name
[WHERE сondition
GROUP BY expression
HAVING condition
ORDER BY expression]
```

Необязательные операторы обрамлены квадратными скобками `[]`.